# String captured from window text invalid as pathname (AutoIT)

Tags: string, split, autoit, file-copying, pathname

I am running into a problem automating an installation procedure. I want to  install a program, and then patch it with a custom UserPatch to remove some glitches.

The UserPatch executable must be run from the installation directory, so I must retrieve this address from the installer. Then, after the program is installed, the script must copy the UserPatch file to the installation directory, and run it from there.

I retrieve the pathname as shown below. The script copies the raw text from the window, which I strip down to just the line containing the pathname.

```
    WinActivate("Dir browse box title")
    $InstallDir = WinGetText("Dir browse box title")
    $split = StringSplit( $InstallDir, "&Path", 1)
    $InstallDir = $split[2]
    $split = StringSplit( $InstallDir, "&OK", 1)
    $InstallDir = $split[1]
    ControlClick("Dir browse box title", "&Drives", "[Class:CButtonClassName; INSTANCE:2]")
    Sleep(100)
```

When printing "$InstallDir" after the above procedure, it shows exactly what I want it to be: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Path to\Installation folder" (without '"').

**The problem is this:** It doesn't copy the file when I run the code snippet below. It **does** work when I hardcode the pathname (commented in the code below), but not when using the $InstallDir variable as retrieved by the code snippet above.

```
; Install the UserPatch
; $InstallDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Path to\Installation folder"
$UserPatchName = "SetupAoC.exe"

FileCopy($UserPatchName, $InstallDir & "\" & $UserPatchName)
Run($InstallDir & "\" & $UserPatchName)

WinWait("SetupAoC - Feature Update Tool")
ControlClick("SetupAoC - Feature Update Tool", "Install", "[Class:DirectUIHWND; INSTANCE:1]")
Send("{SPACE}")
Sleep(2000)
WinClose ("SetupAoC - Install Complete")
WinClose ("SetupAoC - Feature Update Tool")
```

I've got the feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but I really can't tell what the problem is? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT in reply to comments:

After

```
$InstallDir = WinGetText("Dir browse box title")
```

the value of $InstallDir is

```
&Drives
C:\    Crucial M500
&Folders

&Path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Path to\Installation folder
&OK
&Cancel
```

I then use StringSplit, which creates an array of strings, separated by the specified delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem eliminated.

The problem was that my "C:\path...." string was preceded and trailed by two @CRLF characters (new lines). These were also present in the raw data that I copied from the window, as I didn't include them in my delimiters.

I didn't notice them when printing the output, as they're white-space. I found out when writing the $InstallDir variable to a file, in a desperate attempt.

Anyway, Solved with

```
$InstallDir = StringReplace($InstallDir, @CRLF, "")
```

Thanks for the tips, @Matrix and @McBarby!